# Where did new database 'BackupLocDb_###" come from?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

Yesterday I was doing some work on a 3 Node AlwaysOn group of instances, SQL 2014 SP3, and this morning I found there was a database named `BackupLocDb_1260a388-153d-4c86-a30b-0fd3feafb116` on the primary.  I did not create the database, but I am listed as the owner.

Where did this database come from?

Initial attemps to google, lead me to a few AlwaysOn posts but did not mention the database clearly.  I did not find it on DBA.SE either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The database is created when you use the GUI to add databases to the secondary servers, and select the option **Full database and log backup**, you may safely delete it.

> In the Specify a shared network location accessible by all replicas: field, specify a backup share to which all of the server instance that host replicas have read-write access. For more information, see Prerequisites, earlier in this topic. In the validation step, the wizard will perform a test to make sure the provided network location is valid, the test will create a database on the primary replica named **"BackupLocDb_" followed by a Guid** and perform backup to the provided network location, then restore it on the secondary replicas. It is safe to delete this database along with its backup history and backup file in case the wizard failed to delete them. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/use-the-availability-group-wizard-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this James--I've seen that before on some test servers and just never bothered researching it.